# Inserting info from a file into a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, struct

I want to extract data from a file and store them into the myWorld but my for loop doesn't work, the program doesn't loop one time once it gets to the for loop. I'm not sure what the problem is. This is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Country 
 {
  double pop1950;
  double pop1970;
  double pop1990;
  double pop2010;
  double pop2015;
  string name;
 };

const int MAXCOUNTRIES = 300;

struct World 
 {
  int     numCountries;
  Country countries[MAXCOUNTRIES];
 } myWorld;

void printPop ();

int main ()
{
 printPop();
 return 0;
}

void printPop()
{
 ifstream inFile("population.csv");

 if (!inFile.fail())
 {
    cout << "File has opened successfully.";
 }

 if (inFile.fail())
 {
  cout << "File has failed to open.";
  exit(1);
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < MAXCOUNTRIES; i++)
 {
    inFile >> myWorld.countries[i].pop1950 >> myWorld.countries[i].pop1970 >> myWorld.countries[i].pop1990
           >> myWorld.countries[i].pop2010 >> myWorld.countries[i].pop2015;
    getline (cin, myWorld.countries[i].name);
    cout << "loop is running" << endl;
 }

  inFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your loop is running, its just waiting for user input here :

```
getline (cin, myWorld.countries[i].name);
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the program by changing that line.

Comment: @H.C When you get the opportunity, mark this as the answer. David gets points and future readers can easily see that this truly was the answer.